# Pathloss effect MATLAB code

Tags: matlab, signal-energy

I want to implement the pathloss effect using MATLAB simulation. 
I use the D2D path loss model: 
$$148+40\log_{10}(d)$$
I did not find the right way to add the pathloss effect in the received signal, which is a vector of QAM randomly chosen elements.

Answer (score 1):

A propagation loss expressed in decibels is equivalent to an attenuation in linear scale. If you have a loss of `l_dB` (in dB), that's equivalent to an attenuation of `l = 10^(l_dB/20)`. So, if your transmitted signal is `S`, the received signal is `R = S ./ l`.

Note that the factor of 1/20 in the conversion from dB to linear scale is needed because we're scaling the amplitude (voltage) of the signal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer MBaz! this is what I was looking for :)

Comment: Actually, the factor needs to be l=10^(l_db/20) if this is going to scale the amplitude of the signal. If you want to scale the power of the received signal, MBaz is right. See also [e.g. this description](http://dspillustrations.com/pages/posts/misc/decibel-conversion-factor-10-or-factor-20.html).

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé You're right: scaling the amplitude (voltage) requires a factor of 20. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @farfella Glad to be of help; please consider upvoting/accepting the answer :)